# Google mini console access

Tags: google-search-appliance

We have not accessed our admin console in a while and now none of our passwords work. I did click on the 'forgot password' option but did not get anything back. Is there a backdoor to get on it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use "the orange cable"?

Check this link:

https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2673191?hl=en